# Code Coverage Test Class Recursive Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I cannot get my head around code coverage.  I have been given the task to add code to avoid recursive calls. This is pretty straight forward but what I cannot understand is now the code coverage has gone from 95% to 8% by adding one line of code. Why have I tanked my code coverage?

```
trigger SEL_COL_SetIncidentStaffonAction on 
 BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c (before insert) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){

        Set<Id> incIds = new Set<Id>();   

        for (BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c inchist : Trigger.new){
            incIds.add(inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c);              
        }

        Map<Id, BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> incmap = new Map<Id, BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>(
            [
                Select Id, BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c,ownerid,name,SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c from BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c where Id in :incIds
            ]);

        for (BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c inchist : Trigger.new){

            if(incmap!=null)
            {
                if (incmap.get(inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c).BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c != null){
                    inchist.SEL_COL_Incident_Staff__c = incmap.get(inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c).BMCServiceDesk__FKOpenBy__c;
                }

                //if the incident history is related with atos then we put a flag, so Pentaho knows this is related with ATOS.
                if(incmap.get(inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c).SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c!=null){
                    Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
                    Datetime createdDT=Datetime.now();
                    String formattedDate;
                    String formattedDT;

                    if(dt!=null)
                        formattedDate = dt.format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z');

                    if(createdDT!=null)    
                        formattedDT=createdDT.format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z');

                    inchist.transactionDate__c=formattedDate;
                    inchist.createdDateGMT__c=formattedDT;
                    inchist.FTP_To_Process__c=true;
                    inchist.SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c=incmap.get(inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c).SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c;
                }    

            }    

        }
    }
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
(seealldata=true)
public class SEL_COL_SetIncidentStaffonActionTest {


    static testMethod void testIncidentStaff(){

        if (checkRecursivetest.runAfterOnce())
        {


            Profile p = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'ServiceDesk Client'];
            User tuser =    new User(alias='u2',email='u3@sel.col.test.com',
                        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='TestingUser', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                        localesidkey='en_US',profileid=p.Id, country='United States',
                        timezonesidkey='Europe/London',username='u2@sel.col.test.com');

            insert tuser;

            QueueSObject queue = [select QueueId from QueueSObject where SObjectType = 'BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c' limit 1];

            BMCServiceDesk__Status__c status = [select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Status__c where Name = 'WORK IN PROGRESS' Limit 1];
            BMCServiceDesk__Impact__c impact = [select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Impact__c where Name = 'LOW' Limit 1];
            BMCServiceDesk__Urgency__c urgency = [select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Urgency__c where Name = 'LOW' Limit 1];
            BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c service = [select Id from BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c where BMCServiceDesk__ClassID__c = 'BMC_BUSINESSSERVICE' Limit 1];
            BMCServiceDesk__Category__c category = [select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Category__c where BMCServiceDesk__AvailableForIncidents__c = true and BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = false Limit 1];
            String source = 'Telephone';
            String incType = 'Incident';
            String opCat = 'Test';
            String description = 'Test Incient';
            String ref = 'ref';

            BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c Tincident = [SELECT Id, Name, COL_SEL_CC_User__c, SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c, SEL_COL_Site__c, 
                                                       BMCServiceDesk__dueDateTime__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKAccount__c, 
                                                       BMCServiceDesk__FKContact__c, BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c, 
                                                       BMCServiceDesk__FKPriority__c,BMCServiceDesk__FKBMC_BaseElement__c,
                                                       SEL_COL_Site__r.BMCServiceDesk__PostalCode__c, SEL_COL_Site__r.BMCServiceDesk__Address__c,
                                                       SEL_COL_Site__r.BMCServiceDesk__Country__c, SEL_COL_Site__r.BMCServiceDesk__City__c, 
                                                       SEL_COL_Site__r.BMCServiceDesk__StateOrProvince__c, Preferred_Date__c, Preferred_Slot_AM_PM__c
                                                FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c
                                                LIMIT 1]; 


            BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incident = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(BMCServiceDesk__FKClient__c = tuser.Id,
                                                                               COL_SEL_CC_User__c = Tincident.COL_SEL_CC_User__c,

                                                                               SEL_COL_Site__c = Tincident.SEL_COL_Site__c,

                                                                               BMCServiceDesk__FKAccount__c = Tincident.BMCServiceDesk__FKAccount__c, 
                                                                               BMCServiceDesk__FKContact__c = Tincident.BMCServiceDesk__FKContact__c,

                                                                               BMCServiceDesk__FKPriority__c = Tincident.BMCServiceDesk__FKPriority__c,
                                                                               BMCServiceDesk__FKBMC_BaseElement__c = Tincident.BMCServiceDesk__FKBMC_BaseElement__c,


                                                                                BMCServiceDesk__contactType__c = source, BMCServiceDesk__IncidentType__c = incType,
                                                                                BMCServiceDesk__FKBusinessService__c = service.Id, BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c = category.Id, 
                                                                                SEL_COL_Client_Reference__c = ref, OwnerID = queue.QueueId);

    //      Test.startTest();
            insert incident;
    //      Test.stopTest();



            BMCServiceDesk__Action__c action = [Select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Action__c where BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = True and BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = False limit 1];
            BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c inchist = new BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c();
            inchist.BMCServiceDesk__note__c = 'test note';
            inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKAction__c = action.Id;
            inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c = incident.Id;

            Test.startTest();
            insert inchist;
            Test.stopTest();

            // confirm test
            BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c  incidenthist = [select Id, BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c 
                            from BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c 
                            where BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c = :incident.Id limit 1];

            system.assert(incident.Id == incidenthist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c);
        }
    }
}
```

CheckRecursive Class

```
public Class checkRecursive{
    Private static boolean run = true;
    Public static boolean runOnce()
    {
        if(run)
        {
            run=false;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return run;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@isTest(seeAllData=true)` is a red flag. While unlikely to be the cause of your issues, it's still worth mentioning. Best practice is to create the data you need for your test inside the test class itself. Otherwise, you open yourself up to failures due to pre-existing data in one environment that does not exist in the environment you're testing in.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here lies with the mechanism that you're using to prevent recursion.

I honestly couldn't recommend using a static boolean for this (working before insert does mean you don't have access to the record Id though... I'll get back to this later), because using that as the base for recursion prevention means that the code you're protecting will only execute, at most, 1 time for the entire transaction.

Your trigger runs `before insert`. If we look at the test method, we see the following:

```
//Test.startTest();
insert incident;
//Test.stopTest();

BMCServiceDesk__Action__c action = [Select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Action__c where BMCServiceDesk__appliesToIncident__c = True and BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = False limit 1];
BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c inchist = new BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c();
inchist.BMCServiceDesk__note__c = 'test note';
inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKAction__c = action.Id;
inchist.BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__c = incident.Id;

Test.startTest();
insert inchist;
Test.stopTest();
```

You're inserting an incident, and then you're separately inserting an incident history. If inserting an incident causes you to also insert a history record (which would seem to be a reasonable assumption, even though the trigger for that hasn't been provided), then by the time you get to inserting your own history record, your recursion prevention mechanism has already been tripped.

`Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` gives you a new set of limits, *but it does not clear out static variables*.

So, you could make your static boolean `@testVisible` so you can reset it before running your test proper...but there's a smell in your code that should be investigated.

A better recursion prevention mechanism would be to use a `Set<Id>` (the idea being that you check to see if the Id of the current record has already been seen by the code you want to prevent recursion for). A `before insert` trigger does not have `Id` available, but it also should not be able to be called recursively (at least not directly).

Since `before insert` can't be (directly) called recursively, I doubt that placing recursion protection in the place that you have it is the right thing to do. Instead, I'd suggest looking at the code (trigger or otherwise) where you're actually inserting your history records, and place the recursion prevention there instead.

Comment: as a side note - and not a criticism - even the static id sets have issues in certain use cases, notably - a partial success bulk transaction where 1+ recs fail and 1+ recs succeed. SFDC retries the successes but does not roll back the static vbls. Hence, on the retry, the statics will prevent anything from executing